# How to add map() results to a List

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am doing something simple and cannot figure out how to do it.
I have an ArrayList which I used the `stream().map()` method on and I want to immediately add the results to a new ArrayList.

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (list.size() < 5) {
        System.out.println("Enter numbers of the array : ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        list.add(num);
    }
    System.out.print("Before mapping : ");
    list.forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.print("After mapping : ");
    List<Integer> mappedList = new ArrayList<>();
    list.stream().map(n -> n * 3);
    mappedList.forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
```

So I want to do something like `mappedList = list.stream().map(n -> n * 3);`
But that is not the right way to do it.

PS advice on any other section of my code would be appreciated too. Thanks!

Comment: [`Stream::collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)

Comment: You could use something like List<Integer> collect = list.stream().map(n -> n * 3).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collect` method from java Stream library here.

```
List<Integer> mappedList = list.stream()
                                .map(n -> n * 3)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

More on `collect` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-

Answer (score 0):

It will look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (list.size() < 5) {
            System.out.println("Enter numbers of the array : ");
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            list.add(num);
        }
        System.out.print("Before mapping : ");
        list.forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("After mapping : ");
        List<Integer> mappedList = new ArrayList<>();
        mappedList = list.stream().map(n -> n * 3).collect(Collectors.toList());

        mappedList.forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
    }
```